# Convert HTML in Asp.net, Implementing Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am beginner in web development can any one help me out and convert this HTML in ASP.net, I am trying to use this jquery but i am unable to use it. http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
    <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      pick12HourFormat: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: have you imported both the jquery script .js file and the plugin bootstrap-datetimepicker .js file? can you show us the full HTML including the head tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you didn't miss any css or script reference.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <link href="bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                language: 'en',
                pick12HourFormat: true
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
    <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please convert even the body into asp:textbox so that i can collect the data into the .cs file.

Comment: You cannot use server side controls to manipulate date time picker. Try using hidden field: <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
<script>$("#hidden").val($('#date-time-picker').val());</script>
Or post you example so I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are missing any of the css or js references. Below if the example they have will all the required components.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
      <input type="text"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'pt-BR'
      });
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```